# Why there are not any real lightweight threads for python?

Tags: python, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new to Python and seems that the multiprocessing and threads module are not very interesting and suffer from the same problems such as threads in Perl. Is there a technical reason why the interpreter can't use lightweight threads such as posix threads to make an efficient thread implementation that really runs on several cores?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It *is* using POSIX threads. The problem is the [GIL](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf).

Note that the GIL is not part of the Python spec --- it's part of the CPython reference implementation. Jython, for example, does not suffer from this problem.

That said, looked into [Stackless](https://bitbucket.org/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki/Home) ?

Comment: Also, the GIL makes Cpython faster - Many tried but removing it seems to degrade performance.

Comment: nosklo: it may be more accurate to say that the GIL makes single-threaded CPython faster. modifications that removed it managed to make multi-threaded code of parallel algorithms run faster than the equivalent single-threaded implementations, but the speed of single-threaded code was considerably reduced

Comment: Certainly a pity given the importance of multicore chips and scalability.

Comment: @piotr http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/ProjectPlan#Global_Interpreter_Lock The GIL isn't the only thing hindering Python's scalability.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Stackless does not take advantage of multi-cores either.  All tasklets, or so-called lightweight threads, run on the same thread.  No real parallelism is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Piotr,

You might want to take a look at stackless (http://www.stackless.com/) which is a modified version of python running lightweight tasklets in message passing (erlang style) fashion.

I'm not sure if you're looking for a multicore solution, but poking around in stackless might give you what you're looking for.

Ben

Comment: Will it put several cpus to use?

Comment: Not by itself - you might consider twisted for this, although if you were looking for true multicore scalability (without distributing your application) Python might not be the best choice - you may want to consider Erlang.

Comment: I've been reading the reasonings about process scalability. So they say if you really want to scale further than the local cores you will need several process anyway and thus the GIL is not a big deal. Thanks for the Erlang hint, seems that Erlang also does it by process.